# How to get customfield value by woocommerce product ID

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I try to get the value of WooCommerce custom field from an array of product ID. No luck, I'm on the custom page not on the woocommerce loop.

tried this: `$productArray1` is a list of product ID (and it's working)

```
global $wpdb;
global $product;

foreach ($productArray1 as $value)
{
    $querystr = "
    SELECT meta_value
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key
    WHERE $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'product_cip'
    AND $wpdb->posts.$product->ID=$value
    ORDER BY meta_value DESC
    ";

    $productsCIP = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

    if ( ! $productsCIP ) {
        $wpdb->print_error();
    }
    else {
        echo $productsCIP;
    }
};
```

I can get all product with the same customfield like this :

```
$products = wc_get_products( array( 'product_cip' => '3337875548519' ) );
echo 'PRODUCT WITH SAME CIP (TOTAL : '.count($products).')<br>';
```

But I need to find 'product_cip' by product ID.
Any clue?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for all products with same 'product_cip' value try this:

```
$a=array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'    => 'product_cip',
            'value'  => 'some value',
            'compare'=> '='
        )
    ),
    'fields' => 'ids'
);
$b=get_posts($a);
echo count($b);
```

if you have get all products data

```
$products_array=array();
foreach($b as $v){
    $_product=wc_get_product($v);
    echo $_product->get_name().',';
    $products_array[]=$_product;
}
```

Comment: Perfect blanck ! I really appreciated your help, there is lot of way to do on wp...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$product_obj=array();
foreach ($productArray1 as $value)
   {
    $product_obj['id']=$value;
    $product_obj['product_cip']=get_post_meta($value,'product_cip');
   }
```

or

```
foreach ($productArray1 as $value)
   {
    $product_obj['id']=$value;
    $product_obj['product_cip']=get_post_meta($value,'product_cip',true);
   }
echo 'PRODUCT WITH SAME CIP (TOTAL : '.count( $product_obj).')
';
```

if meta value not array.

Comment: Yes! works fine:  array(2) { ["id"]=> string(5) "58240" ["product_cip"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(13) "3323034408701" } } just last question, $productArray1 have more than one ID, how to loop over all ? and get all product_cip ? Thanks a lot blanck !

Comment: foreach loop do it this.echo will be set after foreach(...){ } echo...

Comment: oups my mistake... thanks again blanck !! past some hours to figure out how accomplish this...